# is that of a facilitator while

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

Using a case-based approach engages students in discussion of specific scenarios that resemble or typically are real-world examples. This method is learner-centered with intense interaction between participants as they build their knowledge and work together as a group to examine the case. **The instructor's role is *that of a facilitator while* the students collaboratively analyze and address problems and resolve questions that have no single right answer.**

I cannot make heads or tails of the bold part, especially Italic one.
 What does **that of a something** mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*That* is a very overworked word, because it has at least three distinct uses:

1. As a *subordinating conjunction*<sup>†</sup>

   > John said ***that*** he would play the role of facilitator.
2. As a *relative pronoun*<sup>†</sup>

   > Facilitator is the role ***that*** John played.
3. As a *demonstrative adjective or pronoun*<sup>†</sup>

   > a. ***That*** role is the one which John played.
   >   b. ***That*** is what John did.

In your example, *that* is employed in use 3b: it acts as a demonstrative pronoun<sup>†</sup>, and its *referent* (the entity it refers to) is the noun phrase *The role*:

```
  The instructor's role is    that    of a facilitator.
                               ↓
  The instructor's role is [the role] of a facilitator.
```

*While* does not belong to this clause; it is a *subordinating conjunction*<sup>†</sup> which introduces the following clause and defines its relationship to the preceding main clause. Its literal meaning is "at the same time as", but it carries a contrastive sense as well, emphasizing that in this "learner-centered" approach the instructor's role is reduced and the students themselves perform much of his traditional teaching role.

---

<sup>†</sup> These are the terms employed in the traditional grammar which you are most likely to have encountered. If you have enjoyed a Thoroughly Modern approach to English grammar you may know these as 1. *complementizer*, 2. *relativizer*, 3. *determiner*, and 3b. *fused-head determiner*; and you may have been taught that *while* acts as a *preposition*.